# Ant in Eclipse wants tools.jar but there's no tools.jar in Java 9/10

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx, ant, java-10

I'm trying to build a JavaFX application in e(fx)clipse using the build.fxbuild file. Unfortunately ant complains it can't find `tools.jar`. But `tools.jar` was removed starting from Java 9 (I'm actually using Java 10), so I can't add it to the ant classpath in `Preferences > Ant > Runtime > Classpath`. The actual error message on the console is this:

```
BUILD FAILED
<project_directory>\build\build.xml:59: Unable to find a javac compiler;
com.sun.tools.javac.Main is not on the classpath.
Perhaps JAVA_HOME does not point to the JDK.
It is currently set to "C:\Program Files\Java\jre-10.0.1"
```

My JAVA_HOME environment variable is also set to point to JDK 10, it's included in PATH as well, so I also don't understand the last line. What can I do in this situation?

Comment: in your java folder, check to see if have actually downloaded the JDK, then in your system variable, set JAVA_HOME to your jdk folder

Comment: Your e(fx)clipse installation should use this JDK when you launch your Eclipse instance! (see also https://www.eclipse.org/efxclipse/install.html)

Comment: I had it downloaded, I should have been more clear.

Comment: `"C:\Program Files\Java\jre-10.0.1"` doesn’t sound like it was pointing to a JDK.

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR - update your Eclipse / e(fx)clipse installation.

According<sup>1</sup> to [this blog posting](https://tomsondev.bestsolution.at/2017/08/06/efxclipse-3-0-0-is-released/) [e(fx)clipse 3.0.0](https://projects.eclipse.org/projects/technology.efxclipse/releases/3.0.0/bugs) supports Java 9.  (Apparently a lot of changes were required to get rid of dependencies on Oracle implementation classes.)

The Eclipse project page for [e(fx)clipse 3.0.0](https://projects.eclipse.org/projects/technology.efxclipse/releases/3.0.0/bugs) says that:

- it was released in June 2017
- it is part of the Oxygen release(s)

There is no specific mention of releases supporting Java 10 or later (yet), but [another blog post](https://tomsondev.bestsolution.at/2018/08/04/supporting-openjfx-11-from-jdk11-onwards-in-efxclipse/) talks about how e(fx)clipse will have to cope with JavaFX11 being unbundled from the standard Java SE distributions.

---

<sup>1 - I am not in a position to validate this information ...</sup>

Comment: I have the latest Eclipse Photon and e(fx)clipse version 3.3.0. I don't think the problem is that I'm using Java 10 but who knows. I have the latest everything so I have no idea what's wrong. I forgot to mention even Eclipse complains about the missing tools.jar when I'm on the Ant Classpath tab. Which I guess shouldn't happen if I have everything up to date?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using an older version of eclipse or is your JAVA_HOME incorrect?

- First, download and use java 9 or 10 [**JDK**](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/).
- Set your environment variable correctly (don't use JRE location),
- Update your path to include the bin folder in your JDK folder
- Make sure you have a recent version of [eclipse](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/)

Comment: I am using the newest Eclipse Photon. I have JDK 10, which is in my case definitely located in `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-10.0.1`. JAVA_HOME has exactly this value. Since it did not work with only this, I also added it to the global PATH. And I also included the bin folder but it still doesn't work. Thanks for the suggestions though.

Comment: @tatsletni according to your error message, `JAVA_HOME` is pointing to `"C:\Program Files\Java\jre-10.0.1"`, not `…jdk-10.0.1"`. Mind that the *local* variable values, i.e. in ant’s launch configuration, have precedence over global paths.